# Spring MVC Entities Id (Generated value) separate counter

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, model-view-controller, entity

developping a new Java Spring MVC microservice i have encountered a minor issue.
When i send a creation request for any entity, the id generated always follows the previous one.

[My event entity id configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vtqhm.png)

[My user entity id configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QIvwi.png)

For example, this is what i got from these 2 requests

[User creation request (you can see the id value is 1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a85Bd.png)

[Event creation request (you can see the id value is 2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Icjap.png)

The created event Id is the last created user Id + 1 which i obviously do not want to happen.
I want separate Id values for each entity. I want to know what i am doing wrong.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution worker pretty well ;)
I finally used it and added @SequenceGenerator annotation to initialize the count at 0.

```spring
@SequenceGenerator(name = "seq", initialValue = 0)
public class ClassName {
  
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(generator = "seq")
  private Integer id;

}
```

Thank you very much Daniel, that's kind of you.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `@GeneratedValue` without providing a strategy.

Therefore it uses the `AUTO` strategy by default which indicates that the persistence provider should pick an appropriate strategy for the particular database.

As both ID columns share the same name I assume that both entities share one and the same generator.

Which results in

1. Create event entity with ID = 1 as the generator started at one
2. Create user entity with ID = 1 + 1 as new generated value is requested

You should think about using different sequences for generating separate IDs for each entity.

Following uses a DB sequence to generate an ID

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "my_entity_name_seq")
private long id;
```

If I would not specify a concrete generator in the annotation hibernate ,for example will, create a default sequence called `hibernate_sequence` which is then used for all entities which use `@GeneratedValue` without specifying a generator. This then leads to incremented values over all tables / entities.